# Locating parent elements with parentElementArrayFinder

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

There is a [`parentElementArrayFinder` attribute](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/768fd393d1084a8da0ec6eeaa57508bf17519a3f/lib/element.ts#L817) available on an `ElementFinder` object which, from I understand, may return a parent element of the current:

```
var myElement = $(".myclass");
var parentElement = myElement.parentElementArrayFinder;
```

It is, though, not documented as a part of [Protractor's public API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api). Is `parentElementArrayFinder` a reliable and stable method to locate a parent element and would always return the same element as `myElement.element(by.xpath(".."))`?

Comment: Help me understand why you can't use by.xpath("..")?

Comment: @MichaelWarner I can and do use `..` here and there; `parentElementArrayFinder` is just something that caught my eye and I wonder what purpose does it have and if it can be used. Thanks.

Comment: If i remember correctly `parentElementArrayFinder` holds the methods to retrieve the web elements from a chained locator/filter like `$().$()` or `$$().filter()`. It's not related to the parent element from the DOM.

Comment: @FlorentB. right, that was my thinking initially but I figured to ask that to confirm. Please post as an answer to resolve the topic. Thanks.

Comment: Check this link as it is a similar kind of problem. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/768fd393d1084a8da0ec6eeaa57508bf17519a3f/lib/element.ts#LC817

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize comments, the existing answer, my observations and the source code, `parentElementArrayFinder` should and can only be used if the element you get `parentElementArrayFinder` for was "chained" from an element.

This will work:

```
var parent = element(by.css(".parent"));
var child = parent.element(by.css(".child"));

child.parentElementArrayFinder  # link to "parent" - defined
```

This will not:

```
var child = element(by.css(".child"));

child.parentElementArrayFinder  # no link to "parent" - undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the code for the ElementFinder [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/768fd393d1084a8da0ec6eeaa57508bf17519a3f/lib/element.ts#LC771) which has a prop for `parentElementArrayFinder` [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/768fd393d1084a8da0ec6eeaa57508bf17519a3f/lib/element.ts#LC817).

From what I have found in the code. It throws an error if `parentElementArrayFinder` does not exist.

```
super();
if (!elementArrayFinder) {
  throw new Error('BUG: elementArrayFinder cannot be empty');
}
this.parentElementArrayFinder = elementArrayFinder;
```

From this, we can safely assume it will always be there so I think it is safe to use.